# How to consume a REST API with OAuth 1.0 using DotNetOpenAuth

Tags: c#, rest, access-token, dotnetopenauth, oauth-1.0a

Desperately trying to find a way to use DotNetOpenAuth for consuming a REST API with OAuth 1.0, I do not want to give up on DotNetOpenAuth yet. (I don't seem to be the only one struggling with how to use this giant package. See [Accessing Yelp's OAuth 1.0a API with DotNetOpenAuth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036934/accessing-yelps-oauth-1-0a-api-with-dotnetopenauth) and [DotNetOpenAuth OAuth 1.0a Consumer automation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42513789/dotnetopenauth-oauth-1-0a-consumer-automation) for example. Please give us newbies an easier entry point into OAuth in C#.)

Does somebody know a good tutorial, perhaps leveraging on Microsoft's own REST Client tutorial (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/console-webapiclient) on how to include OAuth 1.0 in a REST consumer?

Any hints and suggestions are much appreciated!